# In Python Panda: Best way to reverse dataframe column values where col1 > col2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a solution, but it uses a for loop and I am looking for a better/ more elegant way to swap Col1 and Col2 values when Col1 > Col2.

Current Solution: 
In 2 for loops:
  Finds Rows where Col1 > Col2
  Then adds row Col2 Col1 Score
Afterwards all rows where Col1 > Col2 are dropped. This only took 2 lines.
Is there a better way to swap the Col1 and Col2 values?

---

```py
import pandas as pd 
def drop_all_revd_in_df(df):
    indexNames = df[ (df['col1'] > df['col2'])].index
    df.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
    return df

# for loops  to check if col1 > col2 and reverse order
def col1GTcol2CleanUp(df):
    col1A_prev = ''
    for col1A in df['col1'] :
        if col1A != col1A_prev :
            col1A_prev = col1A
            for col1B in df[df['col1'] == col1A]['col2']:
                if (col1A > col1B) :
                    score = (df[ (df['col1'] == col1A) & (df['col2'] == col1B)].score).to_frame()['score'].iloc[0] 
                    df =  df.append({'col1' : col1B , 'col2' : col1A ,'score' : score}, ignore_index=True)
    df = drop_all_revd_in_df(df)   
    return df

# initialize list of lists 
dataShort = [["Andy", "Claude", 15],
             ["Vincent", "Frida", 12],  # NOT OK
             ["Vincent", "Pablo", 11]]  # NOT OK

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(dataShort, columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'score']) 
print(df)

col1GTcol2CleanUp(df).sort_values(['col1','col2']).reset_index(drop='True')
```

```
Output:
      col1    col2  score
0     Andy  Claude     15
1  Vincent   Frida     12
2  Vincent   Pablo     11

Out[1]:
    col1    col2    score
0   Andy    Claude  15
1   Frida   Vincent 12
2   Pablo   Vincent 11
```

Comment: Don't post images, use text to post the code and sample data

Comment: This is part of an answer to course answer. We were asked to post code as image if shared anywhere. Its not what is needed to get to final answer, but... Should I still post the code?

Comment: I already have 100%. I am looking for a better way. I am disappointed if we are not allowed to look for better way when learning. Please explain why the question is bad. The class told us to ask in StackOverflow

Comment: I didn't get the part `col1 >col2`. How do you define this? Is it based on the length of `str` ?

Comment: col1 and col2 are strings and its based on what sorting the dataframe would accept as greater than.    However I was looking for general answer where it could be a number (like an id), too. The simple swapping was something I had been unable to do except in for loops, which seemed like a very inelegant and potentially slow solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?
'May' be done through lambda as well - for simplicity, I have put the logic in a separate function.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['Andy','Vincent','Vincent'], 'col2':['Claude','Frida','Pablo'], 'score':[15,12,11]})
df
```

Original / input dataframe:

[image]

Code to achieve desired o/p:

```
def check_row(row):
    if row['col1'] > row['col2']:
        row['col1'],row['col2'] = row['col2'],row['col1'] 
        return row
    else:
        return row
df = df.apply(check_row, axis =1)
df
```

O/P:

[image]

Comment: Thanks . I guess not knowing how to use apply and not knowing row['N1'],row['N2'] = row['N2'],row['N1'] was possible is something that everyone already knows and should not ask = makes this a bad question?

Comment: @traisen: not an awful question for sure :) probably, needed some clarification which is fine now. If the answer above works for you, please accept :)

Comment: Accepted. Question must be awful to get -1 or ?  But I learned 2 new things from the accepted answer as indicated, so very glad I asked.

Comment: @traisen: No worries - We all learn here. Your edited question now(code rather than image of the code) helps to copy/ test/ replicate the input data/problem easy.  I have edited my answer to reflect exactly your data now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the answer by instinct246: Pandas .apply() method tends to be slow. Here's yet another approach (method1 in the code below), it's quite a bit faster, but needs temporary storage for an extra column. This can also be written on a single line (method2 in the code below), even faster, but needs temporary storage for two columns.

```
np.random.seed(113)
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.random.randint(low=0, high=9, size=10000, dtype='int32'),
                   'col2':np.random.randint(low=0, high=9, size=10000, dtype='int32')})

def method1(df):
    """ Modifies df in place, no return value """
    df['col_tmp'] = df[['col1','col2']].max(axis=1)
    df['col1'] = df[['col1','col2']].min(axis=1)
    df['col2'] = df['col_tmp']
    del df['col_tmp']

def method2(df):
    """ Modifies df in place, no return value """
    df['col1'], df['col2'] = df[['col1','col2']].min(axis=1), df[['col1','col2']].max(axis=1)

# instinct246's answer

def check_row(row):
    if row['col1'] > row['col2']:
        row['col1'],row['col2'] = row['col2'],row['col1'] 
        return row
    else:
        return row

def method3(df):
    """ Returns modified df """
    return df.apply(check_row, axis =1)
```

Running `%%timeit` returns:

```
method1: 1.92 ms ± 62.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
method2: 1.31 ms ± 11.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
method3: 558 ms ± 8.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks - You even did timing tests for me.  I need to do timing test on my original solutions, too. If results interesting. I will comment here.      Did you just do on 1 row, or in for loop?    Anyway if really interested again I need to do my own timing tests.

Comment: @traisen The testing was done on 10000 rows, as the code shows above. The macro %%timeit runs it repeatedly until sufficient runtime data is collected to compute mean and standard deviation, as the results show above.